# Attachment through ASANA API

Tags: asana

How can we pass attachment though asana API (JSON), i could not see any reference in the documentation provided.

I like to send WORD/Xls docs through API, let me know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Woop woop! New API feature alert: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/attachments

In addition to being able to fetch attachments, you can now upload them via the API.

Please let us know if you run into any issues, it's a new feature so there may yet be use cases we haven't fully worked through. Keep the feedback coming!

Comment: Thanks

Almost every API call is working for me except this attachment. I tried every option like absolute path, relative path, local web folder and HTTP path. But same error

URL:https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/[task ID]/attachments

Parsing Data:{    "data": {        "id": [Task ID],        "name": "file: http://XXX/images/Product/medium/image.jpg"   }}


some of the options i tried


file@:image.jpg --
file@:/image.jpg --
file:/image.jpg--
/image.jpg--
image.jpg--


ERROR:

{"errors":[{"message":"file: Missing input"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible as per another Stackoverflow thread / Asana developer documentation